# Setting custom TrustManager moving from CFX to RESTEASY in openliberty

Tags: open-liberty

We use to specify custom trustall TrustManager in dev using `ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext()` with `CXF` in openliberty. It was also working with `JerseyClientBuilder`.
Now that we moved features to jakarta, internal implementation moved to `RESTEASY` and seems that our trustmanager is no more invoked and replace by default one defined server.xml.
How can this be achieved now without introducing dependencies on RESTEASY ?